# An example of a reducible random walk on groups?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Random walk on group is defined in the following way as a Markov chain.

> [image]

A theorem says the uniform distribution is stationary for all random walk on groups.

> [image]

If the random walk is irreducible, for example, on a cyclic group $\Bbb Z_n$, then the stationary distribution is unique and hence uniform. My question is, is there any good example of **reducible random walk on groups** so that the uniform distribution is not the only stationary distribution?

It is really hard for me to imagine such a reducible random walk. All examples for random walk on groups given in the textbook so far are irreducible. Hope someone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite true that any random walk on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is irreducible. This will depend on the increment distribution $\mu$ as well.

For example, on $\mathbb{Z}_4$ if you take $\mu(g)=\delta_{g+2}$ then there are two communicating classes $\{0,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}.$ There are lots of different stationary distributions for this random walk.